# localize an "asp.net 7.0 razor pages" application using a single resource file

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-localization

how is it possible to configure the middleware to localize an "asp.net 7.0 razor pages" application (no mvc) using a single resource file?

I tried with the following configuration:

```
string culture = "it";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<OWsefaWebContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("OWsefaWebContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'OWsefaWebContext' not found.")));

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(opts =>
            {
                opts.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                {
                    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
                    return factory.Create(nameof(SharedResource), assemblyName.Name!);
                };
            })
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

        var app = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            DataInitializer.Initialize(services);
        }

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRequestLocalization(culture);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting()
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapRazorPages();
        app.Run();
```

But it seems not to be enough.

Page localization:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
@inject IStringLocalizer localizer
@model OWsefa.Web.Pages.Companies.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h1>Index</h1>
<h1>@localizer["Text.Index"]</h1>
```

When I run the application I get the following error:
*InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer' has been registered.*

Who can help me?

Thank you.

ste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer' has been
> registered.

To avoid this error. try to add  specify  supplying Resource class name like `IStringLocalizer<ResourceClassName>`:

Change the :

```
@inject IStringLocalizer localizer
```

into:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer
```