# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Razor Page View Model's localizated strings display only as Keys

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0, asp.net-core-localization

I use ASP.NET Core 7.0
I'm trying to localize the login error message (or any other string) on my Identity/Account/Login razor page (it has been generated by the Visual Studio 2022 earlier on, so it resides in Root-Folder/Areas/Identity/Account/Login.cshtml)
I've figured out what for my project's structure I've got to add an exact same folder structure for my resources files to make the IViewLocalizer correctly displaying localized text:
[MyPagesFolderStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9KZO.png)
But then the problem arises with IStringLocalizer because, as I read [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-7.0#dataannotations-localization), the IStringLocalizer requires some other resources file, placed elswhere. And this is where the problem arises, as I can't find an appropriate combination of folders and file name to make this working... [errorMsg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LjHJ.png)
As it may be seen - IViewLocalizer which I use in my Razor Pages for displaying localized strings on the razor page itself (Polish signs) is working well, but the IStringLocalizer - don't.

## Configuration

Program.cs:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[] { "pl-PL", "en-US" };
                var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
                    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

                options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
                };
            });

            (...)
            (and at the end...)

            var app = builder.Build();

            var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()?.Value;
            if (localizationOptions != null)
            {
                app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
            }

            (...)
```

I tried mentioned in the docs localization of those resx files (instead of Resources/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/resxFiles I used
Resources/ViewModels/Identity/Account/resxFiles
or even
Resources/ViewModels/Identity/Pages/Account/resxFiles

None of the above seems to work

Actually as I reviewed [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316397/localize-an-asp-net-7-0-razor-pages-application-using-a-single-resource-file) it gave me some hint, about something called "SharedResource" but actually C# comment of this IStringLocalizer seems misleading in this idea: [comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXmCL.png)

If there is someone who knows where is this IStringLocalizer looking for the resx files... Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: funny stuff is, what I've seen that it looks for a subfolder named Resources within a Resources folder like so: (MyProjectRootFolder)/Resources/Resources and when I delete configuration options `options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"` then IStringLocalizer starts to work correctly, but IViewLocalizer stops... FFS xD

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the easiest solution of this issue is to write a custom IStringLocalizer, which use JSON files instead of resx

https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/json-based-localization-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: An example would be userful here. Would you be able to share that custom IStringLocalizer?

Comment: Sure, here's the source I got code from: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/json-based-localization-in-aspnet-core/